# Download file using curl in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, api, curl

I'm trying to download a file using and API endpoint. The following command works in CMD:
`curl http://localhost:8042/endpoint/file > file.extension`

How can I include this command in NodeJS?
I've tried using `node-libcurl` but I can't set the name of the file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the node code which didn't work.

Comment: `require("child_process").exec("curl ... > file.extension")`

Comment: This is no `node-libcurl` code. See the examples on https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-libcurl#simple-request---using-curl-class how to use the library.

Comment: Didn't have a code for it other than setting the URL, because the library needs options parameters, but I don't know what the parameter is for files and couldn't find on the documentation. @LawrenceCherone 's solution works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@Lawrence Cherone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/661872/lawrence-cherone)
This works amazingly.
`require("child_process").exec("curl ... > file.extension")`

Comment: np, Occam's Razor

Comment: Using exec to download large files might result `maxBuffer length exceeded` errors. Would recommend using `spawn` instead.